# Checkchanged not firing when inside a gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview and inside it is a checkbox for the status of the items,
the checkbox has checkchanged event but when I'm trying to check or uncheck it, the checkchanged is not firing.

here is the code for the gridview with checkbox inside

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dgvItems" runat="server" OnRowCreated="dgvItems_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="dgvItems_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgvItems_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDeleting="dgvItems_RowDeleting">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Status">
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chkStatus" runat="server" Checked = <%# (string)Eval("item_status") == "Active" ? true : false %> OnCheckedChanged="chkStatus_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

 protected void chkStatus_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = dgvItems.SelectedRow;
        string item_id = row.Cells[0].Text.ToString();

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Items set item_status = 'Inactive' where item_id = @item_id ",con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", cmd);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are coming to my mind:

1. Your `Page_Load` does not take care of the `IsPostBack`-property, so you are always databinding the grid, even on postback. That prevents events.
2. `GridViewRow row = dgvItems.SelectedRow;` is `null`.

Use this code to get the `GridViewRow` from the checked `CheckBox`:

```
CheckBox chkStatus = (CheckBox) sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) chkStatus.NamingContainer;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! the isPostBack prevents the checkchanged

Answer (score 0):

If your checked state is initially false, then setting it to false again doesn't fire the `CheckedChanged` event.
That happens because the checked state isn't actually changed

This is the internal code used when trying to set the  `CheckBox1.Checked` property

```
public void set_Checked(bool value)
{
if (value != this.Checked)
{
    this.CheckState = value ? CheckState.Checked : CheckState.Unchecked;
}
}
```